# Why the status flags in AVR are on after one's-complementing a zeroed register?

Tags: assembly, avr, ones-complement

I have a code in assembly and I have to find out why the status flags are on

One of the codes is

```
LDI R16, 0
COM R16
```

the result was 0xFF
But I don’t understand why the `S` and `C` flags were on.

Answer (score 0):

COM isn't "complete", it's "one's complement" (bitwise inversion).  Read the manual which explains how each instruction sets flags. http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-7066B778-FBFB-4B81-A2B1-5E04395FB24D.html

It describes the "operation" as `Rd ← $FF - Rd` - I guess AVR's Carry flag [is inverted on subtract (a not-borrow)](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21861/what-cpu-architecture-was-first-to-implement-inverted-borrow-carry-flag-during) like ARM?  Yes, we can see [from the docs for `sub`](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-7066B778-FBFB-4B81-A2B1-5E04395FB24D) that it sets `C` if `sub Rd, Rr` has `Rd >= Rr`, if I'm reading that right?  Hmm, there's stuff about "absolute value" that seems odd, not 100% sure it's equivalent to what ARM does, although I'd guess so for its `sub` / `sbc` to work.

So I think `com` sets flags exactly `sub` from `$ff`, which is probably easy for an AVR to implement internally.

---

[The documentation](http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-0B644D8F-67E7-49E6-82C9-1B2B9ABE6A0D-en-US-1/GUID-3EB1664B-AB2D-4589-9D5E-B2EA78A26EDE.html) for how `com` actually sets status flags specifically says it always sets C to 1.  So of course it always does that.  The interesting part is that that's probably because `0xff - anything` can't have unsigned overflow and wrap around producing a borrow.

The N flag is set according to the result, V (signed overflow) is always cleared, and S = N^V is thus set according to the high bit of the register which in your case became 1.